# doesn't understand this function - How to count word in word

Tags: python, python-3.x

Doesn't understand how this Python function works. I know what it does, supposed to count word in another word, but don't know how it works. Love to hear an explanation.

The function:

```
# Write your count_multi_char_x function here:
def count_multi_char_x(word, x):
  splits = word.split(x)
  print(splits)
  return(len(splits)-1) # Why?

# Uncomment these function calls to test your  function:
print(count_multi_char_x("mississippi", "iss"))
# should print 2
print(count_multi_char_x("apple", "pp"))
# should print 1
```

Comment: Think about how `str.split` works. What does the output of `print(splits)` tell you?

Comment: @wjandrea your comment should have been the answer, because it gfives the OP a hint from which they can try to find+learn the answer and so gain insight/understanding, without giving them the answer on a plate. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

When you split by x :

If the length of the split result is 2, it means you have 1 x, that splits the result to 2 values.

If the length of the split result is 3, it means you have 2 x, that split the result to 3 values.

If the length of the split result is n, it means you have n-1 x, that split the result to n values.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take it step by step. so for the mississippi example `word` will equal `"mississippi"` and `x` will equal `"iss"`. So first this line

```
splits = word.split(x)
```

this takes "mississippi" and splits it by "iss". This gives us `["m", "", "ippi"]`

```
return len(splits) - 1
```

since the list has 3 items, and there were only 2 "iss"'s, we can just take away 1.

This results in the final result of `2`

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_multi_char_x(word, x): 
    # split word on every occurrence of x
    # 'apple' and x='pp' becomes: ['a', 'le']
    # 'mississippi' and x='iss' becomes: ['m', '', 'ippi']
    # so you even get an empty string if x occurs right after another
    splits = word.split(x)
    # get the amount of splitted results and subtract 1
    # because you end up with one more substring than the amount of occurrences
    return len(splits) - 1
```

Comment: My question to you is that, why the output differs, like for `mississipi` it is `['m', '', 'ippi']`, and for `apple` it is `['a', 'le']`?

Comment: @Alok think about what the split is doing and write down for each occurrence of the split string what is between two splits, or before the first occurrence or after the last occurrence. What should the output be if you split 'apppple' on 'pp'?

Comment: What do you mean why? Obviously you will get different outputs when you use different inputs. When you're splitting `mississippi` on `iss` you get `m`, an empty string between the two `iss`s and `ippi`. When you're splitting `apple` on `pp` you get `a` and `le`. The split function returns a list of the results, thus the `[ ]`.

Comment: That doesn't help @barny, I totally get what the `split()` is doing, but my question is, why the difference, why not `['a', '', 'le']` with `['m', '', 'ippi']` or `['m', 'ipi']` with `['a', 'le']`?

Comment: That means @ChristopherKrause, if the occurrence of the target word is more than once, there will be an empty string between the splitter result, like `mississipi`?

Comment: Write down the string you are splitting, then identify from start to finish each occurrence of the split string. What is before the first occurrence, between subsequent occurrences, and after the last occurrence? This is what the result of `split()` is. Go on, do it.

Comment: If you do `results=a.split(x)` then you will get the same output as `a` from `b=x.join(results)`

Answer (score 0):

The split() method splits a string into a list. You can specify the separator, default separator is any whitespace.

Syntax:

```
string.split(separator, max)
```

Parameters Values:

```
separator: Optional. Specifies the separator to use when splitting the string. 
           Default value is a whitespace
max: Optional. Specifies how many splits to do. 
     Default value is -1, which is "all occurrences"
```

For example, if I run following code :

```
txt = "apple#banana#cherry#orange"
x = txt.split("#")
print(x)
```

Will print =>

```
['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'orange']
```

If you see this output there are 4 elements(n) in the list and there were 3 (`n-1`)separators in string.

similarly in function `count_multi_char_x`, the substring `iss` is used as separator to split the string `mississippi`. `print(splits)` gives an output of `['m', '', 'ippi']`. So to count the number of substring(`iss`) in the string(`mississippi`), number of elements in the list minus 1 is done.

Hope the explanation helps.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

answer of your "why" question is because **two separator make string to three parts**. four separator, five and ...

I think split work like this:
 'mississippi' => 'm' , 'issippi' => 'm', '', 'ippi'

for 'issippi':

> 'iss' is between '' and 'ippi'